# protocol adapter error with sqlplus

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

I am trying to connect my `Oracle Database 10g Express Edition` with `sql*plus`. when i start the `sql*plus` command window the following error occurs.
[image]

could you please show me the way of avoiding this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the 2nd result from a Google search on the error message:

Typically this will result from

1. not having ORACLE_SID properly set. Especially so on Windows.
2. not having the db service started. See the windows services applet, services.msc

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2425280